# XPath get multiple nodes with multiple condition

Tags: xml, xpath

I search The names of people who have booked exactly twice.

in xml code below for exemple
Jean Dufour to be reserved exactly twice

```xml
<trainStation>
  <train number="t5560" type="TGV">
    <wagon number="v1">
      <booking number="r17" id="u55"/>
      <booking number="r18" id="u52"/>
    </wagon>
    <wagon number="v2"/>
    <wagon number="v3"/>
    <wagon number="v4">
      <bar service="froid uniquement"/>
    </wagon>
  </train>
  <train number="t6731">
    <wagon number="v1"/>2<wagon number="v2">
      <booking number="r15" id="u55"/>
    </wagon>
  </train>
  <user id="u55" name="Jean" firstName="Dufour"/>
  <user id="u52" name="Brigitte" firstName="Lefebvre"/>
  <user id="u56" name="Patrick" firstName="Subiran"/>
</trainStation>
```

I trie this xpath querie but doesn't work

```xml
//usager[count( @id = //resa/@id)=2 ]
```

Comment: Can you use xquery?

Comment: thank you for answer ,it turns out it's impossible, with xpath